# Attempted to read or write protected memory when using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, access-violation

An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in StatCentric.Tracker.Worker.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

**I've read numerous posts on both Stack Overflow and various blogs and can't seem to find a solution for this.**

I'm doing something very basic:

```
public void Execute(ITrackerRequestModel model)
{
    PageviewRequest p = (PageviewRequest)model;

    using (var db = new StatCentricEntities())
    {
        db.SetTimeout(60);
        db.sp_Log_PageView2(p.SiteId, p.DateTimeUtc, p.vid, p.QueryString, p.p, p.t);
    }
}
```

But this error pops up every time I try to call db.sp_Log_PageView2. This only seems to happen inside my worker role (I'm using Windows Azure).

Also worthy of note is that I'm using the Windows Azure Emulator and I am on Windows 8.1.

I've tried the following:

1. Doing a winsocket reset
2. Disabling JIT debugging (native,script, managed)
3. Disabling JIT debugging on module load
4. Followed some old posts to hot fixes that seem to be specific to .NET
   2.0 and discontinued.
5. Did a memory diagnostic with no issues to make sure it wasn't my hardware.

I am running Visual Studio as administrator and connecting to a remote SQL Server Database hosted in Azure.

Any ideas on how to resolve or further diagnose this are appreciated.

Comment: Are you accessing the same context from different threads because EF is not Thread Safe

Comment: It creates a new instance of the content for every database operation, so no sharing.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not real fix but while waiting for fix from Microsoft you can use this workaround.*

I have same problem. I also tried everything to solve that issue. After few days I gave up and used manual "workaround". It only took few minutes to copy and convert existing sproc calls to new ones.

Just ignore auto generated functions and manually call stored procedures. You can use auto generated classes for returned data. Copy and modify existing function and you will get easily correct parameter names and types.

Just implement partial class to different file:

```
public partial class StatCentricEntities
{
    public virtual List<sp_Log_PageView2_Result> my_sp_Log_PageView2(
        Guid? siteId, 
        DateTime time, 
        string param3, 
        string param4 )
    {
        return Database.SqlQuery<sp_Log_PageView2_Result>(
               "sp_Log_PageView2 @siteId @time @param3 @param4",
                new SqlParameter("siteId", siteId),
                new SqlParameter("time", time),
                new SqlParameter("param3", param3),
                new SqlParameter("param4", param4)).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot when I'm debugging this code again.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this "Attempted to read or write protected memory exception" error while using a SQL Server stored procedure that had an output parameter of type 'Date'.  I tried various things without success and, in the interest of time, settled on the following solution.

1) Remove the output parameter of type date

2) Return a string via a select statement

```
SELECT CONVERT(char(10), @AsOfDate, 20) AS AsOfDate
```

3) Convert the string returned from the stored procedure to a DateTime value in C#

```
DateTime asOfDate = DateTime.Now;
using (var context = new DA.MyEntities())
{
    var procResult = context.myStoredProcedure(myParameter).FirstOrDefault();
    DateTime.TryParse(procResult, out asOfDate);
}
```

I'm not super happy with this compromise, but it did allow me to move forward.